# How do you move your ".ant/lib" directory when ANT runs in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ant

I am using Ant in Eclipse (MS Windows), and I would like to put my .ant/lib directory somewhere else than in my "user home". I would like a solution that does not involve changing the "run configuration" of every individual ant file, because I keep switching project, and I don't want to have to reconfigure it every time. I would also prefer to be able to do this without changing my "user home" globally for Eclipse (I tried this too, using the -user option, and it did not have any effect). I also tried simply moving the directory where I want it, and passing -lib as parameter in the run configuration but ANT said it "did not support -lib" (when run in Eclipse). If I pass -lib as ANT_OPTS (set in the OS), it has not effect. If I add every jar individually in the "user library" part of the run configuration (which is a real pain), it works partly, put the Ant view still shows missing task, so I don't think this is the right way either. I also tried adding the jars in the Ant installation inside Eclipse itself, but Ant does not see them. It only sees it's own jars, probably because they are hardwired in some Manifest.

Is moving ".ant/lib" (in Eclipse) at all possible?

[EDIT] "-user" does not work, but "-Duser.home=" does work. So I get the directory moved, if I move *everything* else. Not great, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

From ant manual: http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html

```
The order in which jars are added to the classpath is as follows:

-lib jars in the order specified by the -lib elements on the command line
jars from ${user.home}/.ant/lib (unless -nouserlib is set)
jars from ANT_HOME/lib
```

So, if you install ant to c:/apps/ant and, set environment variable ANT_HOME to c:/apps/ant, you will get a single re-usable ant installation across all projects.

Eclipse(I am on 3.7.1)  allows to use external ant by providing ant_home - Preferences->Ant->Runtime [ Classpath tab has ANT HOME button]

[image: eclipse setting to setup external ant]

Comment: I did not know about the -nouserlib,. But the rest unfortunately does not directly apply to Eclipse. I know where "ANT_HOME/lib" is in Eclipse, and putting jars there has *no effect at all*. The problem is simply that Ant in Eclipse doesn't follow Ant's own specification. -lib doesn't work either. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @SebastienDiot : It may be case, that ant launcher in eclipse is not following ant documentation. It looks like you can use ant as external tool- http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-ant-version.htm   . That should atleast will ensure the 'ant' startup is same in eclipse and command line